# how to filter magento 2 collection with 'or', 'and' combination?

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

For example, the search query is 'samsung lcd'. it can match with product name or SKU.

I have below product names.

```
1.samsung xyz lcd.

2.samsung lcd pack.

3.samsung mobile

4.screen lcd.
```

so when I filter I need to get only

```
 1.samsung xyz lcd.

 2.samsung lcd pack.

where name like '%samsung lcd%' or sku like '%samsung lcd%' or (name like '%samsung%' or sku like '%samsung%' and(name like '%lcd%' or sku like '%lcd%'))
```

but now I'm getting all above product names.
Could you please help me with this.

```
$term = $this->getRequest()->getParam('term');
$termArr = explode(' ', $term);
$search = array();
$search[] = array('attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%' . $term . '%');
$search[] = array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $term . '%');
        foreach ($termArr as $termc) {
            $search[] = array(
                'attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $termc . '%');
            $search[] = array(
                'attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%' . $termc . '%');
        }

  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter($search);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $collection->setPageSize(10);
```

update:
The following code is working fine, but not optimized.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $term = $this->getRequest()->getParam('term');
    $termArr = explode(' ', $term);      
    $pids = array();
    if (count($termArr)) {
        $collection1 = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
        foreach ($termArr as $termc) {
            $termc = trim($termc);
            if ($termc == '')
                continue;

            $search1 = array();
            $search1[] = array(
                'attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $termc . '%');
            $search1[] = array(
                'attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%' . $termc . '%');
            $collection1->addFieldToFilter($search1);
        }
        $collection1->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $collection1->getSelect()->columns(['entity_id']);           
        $pids = $collection1->getAllIds();
    }
    $collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $search = array();
    $search[] = array('attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%' . $term . '%');
    $search[] = array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $term . '%');
    if (count($pids)) {
        $search[] = array('attribute' => 'entity_id', 'in' => $pids);
    }
    $collection->addFieldToFilter($search);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $collection->setPageSize(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try with below code :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$term.'%'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => '%'.$term.'%'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$collection->setPageSize(10);
```

Comment: it will show only 2nd option.2.samsung lcd pack

Comment: I need 1 & 2 options.

Comment: Please try and check, it should work because I am calling addAttributeToFilter() method two times. In magento it works as AND operator.

Comment: where name like '%samsung lcd%' or sku like '%samsung lcd%' or (name like '%samsung%' or sku like '%samsung%' and(name like '%lcd%' or sku like '%lcd%'))

Comment: Remove below code -

Comment: $termArr = explode(' ', $term);
$search = array();
$search[] = array('attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%' . $term . '%');
$search[] = array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $term . '%');
        foreach ($termArr as $termc) {
            $search[] = array(
                'attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $termc . '%');
            $search[] = array(
                'attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%' . $termc . '%');
        }

Comment: it will give all 4 names.it is not working